# ASP.NET Repeater ItemDataBound happening AFTER PreRender event?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, events, repeater, page-lifecycle

I have a repeater control on an ASP.NET 2.0 web form.

As I understanding it, all of the page's data-bound controls fire their binding events somewhere in between the `Page_Load` and the `Page_PreRender` events.

However, my repeater's `ItemDataBound` event appears to be happening AFTER the `PreRender` event.

How is this so and is there any way I can access the page controls AFTER all the `ItemDataBound` events have fired?

**Updates:**

- The Repeater uses an `ObjectDataSource` with the `DataSourceID` declarative set in the repeater control.
- The DataSource ID or object is not modified at all during the page life-cycle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declarative databinding (datasource specified via the DataSourceID property) occurs later than the PreRender event. The behavior you are observing is by design. If this is not what you need you should explicitly databind your control - just call its DataBind method.

Comment: If that is true than how do you explain this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

PreRender | Before this event occurs:

Each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method.

Comment: I tested with a simple page. Here is the order in which the events were executed:
Page_Load
Page_PreRender
Repeater1_DataBinding
Repeater1_ItemDataBound
Repeater1_PreRender
According to Reflector the Repeater.EnsureDataBound is called in Repeater.OnPreRender.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks! Looks like the repeater is not your average data-bound control!

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifically binding your repeater (myRepeater.DataBind();) in your code behind file (for example inside the Page_Load() event)?

Have you checked out the ASP.NET events lifecycle? Sorry if you already know this, but just in case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Hope it helps.

Ricardo.

Comment: Nope. The repeater's databind is not explicitly called. That's why I figured it would occur after the page Load but before the PreRender, as stated by the page lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar situation, and my option was to FORCE the controls to bind themselves, by calling EnsureChildControls or some similar method.

Comment: I know I can force it to databind during Page_Load, but I was just curious as to WHY it was waiting until after the Page_PreRender to bind. Wierd!